# TypeError is Null

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, typeerror

I'm fixing a simple user input mulptiplication table which has been littered with errors.
I'm stuck with a partucular piece of code and do not understand what it means.

When the script is run in firbug it says `"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"`

This is the code which is attached to html:

```
var get = function(name){return document.getElementById("name").value;};

var set = function(name,value){document.getElementById("name").value=value;};
```

Comment: Are you sure is DOM loaded when you call `getElementById`?

Comment: Thanks guys I think I understand now what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code is meant to query the DOM for an element with the id of `name`:

```
var get = function(name){return document.getElementById(name).value;};
var set = function(name,value){document.getElementById(name).value=value;};
```

Answer (score 2):

That simply means that there is no element with an `id` property of `"name"` in the DOM. Perhaps your code runs before the document is ready?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the element with `id = "name"` is not found in document. Look in the dom if it exists.
You can also try to add this code as event handler for `ready`-event to check that it works ok there - as it is already said maybe you run this code before the dom is loaded.